# Why can't I see any e-mail coming in into my mail-catcher

Tags: php, symfony, email, symfony-mailer

it's my first time using mail catcher and I was wondering why my code runs through for sending an e-mail but I don't see anything in my mail hog / mail catcher.

Here is how I send my e-mail

Config:

```
###> symfony/mailer ###
MAILER_DSN=smtp://email@email.com:PASS@sslout.df.eu:465
###< symfony/mailer ###
```

These are the actual live configs, which are in my .env file

Then I shave a simple form

```
 <section>

                {{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'custom-form'}}) }}

                <form method="post" action="#">
                    <div class="fields">
                        <div class="field half">
                            {{ form_row(form.name, {'attr': {'class': 'form-row'}}) }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="field half">
                            {{ form_row(form.email, {'attr': {'class': 'form-row'}}) }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            {{ form_row(form.message, {'attr': {'class': 'form-row'}}) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="actions">
                        {{ form_row(form.submit, {'attr': {'class': 'form-row'}}) }}
                    </ul>
                </form>
            </section>

            {{ form_end(form) }}
```

And this is how I send my e-mail

```
    /**
 * @var MailerInterface
 */
private MailerInterface $mailer;

/**
 * @param MailerInterface $mailer
 */
public function __construct(MailerInterface $mailer)
{
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
}


#[Route('/', name: 'app_contact')]
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(ContactFormType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $data = $form->getData();

        try {
            $this->sendMail(
                $data['name'],
                $data['email'],
                $data['message'],
            );
            
        } catch (\Exception $e) {

            $e->getMessage();


        }

        header('/');

      //  return $this->render('contact/success.html.twig');

    }



    return $this->render('contact/contact.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}

/**
 * @param MailerInterface $mailer
 * @throws \Symfony\Component\Mailer\Exception\TransportExceptionInterface
 */
public function sendMail($name, $email, $message)
{
    $sendTo = 'contact@build-yourself';

    $email = (new Email())
        ->from($email)
        ->to($sendTo)
        ->subject('Contact Email from: ' . $name)
        ->text($message);

    $this->mailer->send($email);

}
```

When I debug the send function it says that everything is okay and it runs, why can't I see my sent e-mail inside my mailhog

```
  mailhog:
image: mailhog/mailhog
ports:
  - 1025:1025 # smtp server
  - 8025:8025 # web ui
```

Comment: Try changing your mailer DSN to `MAILER_DSN="smtp://127.0.0.1:1025"` for mailhog

Comment: @Brent I was experiment with different settings.

I tried with localhost and 127 and i get

`"Connection could not be established with host "127.0.0.1:1025": stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:1025 (Connection refused)"`

Comment: I also tried  `MAILER_DSN=smtp://localhost` but here I get

`Connection could not be established with host "localhost:25": stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to localhost:25 (Cannot assign requested address)`

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but it seems like you're using docker. Docker networking can be annoying. Try [@MewTwo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9953906/mewtwo)'s answer and change it to `smtp://mailhog:1025`

Answer (score 0):

*it seems that you can't upvote an answer if it works for you since you don't have enough reputation but you can answer*

what worked for me and what answered some of you, **for those using Docker**

adding in .env `MAILER_DSN=smtp://{container name}:1025`

I was using the **schickling/mailcatcher** docker image for mailcatcher and the `MAILER_DSN=smtp://mailer:1025` worked

Answer (score -1):

Here is how it worked for me

```
 MAILER_DSN=smtp://mailhog:1025
```